# Recursive loop not having expected behavior

Tags: python, recursion

So I create a tree in python. I am trying to change some value of every child of the root node. But, every node in my tree is not being hit.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value, priority):
        self.parent = None
        self.children = []
        self.value = value
        self.priority = priority

    def add_child(self, obj):
        self.children.insert(obj)
        obj.parent = self

    def getChildren(self):
        return self.children.getAll()

tom = Node("DD",1)
tom.add_child(Node("a",0.3))
tom.add_child (Node("b", 0.6))

tom.getChildren()[0].add_child(Node("c",1))
tom.getChildren()[1].add_child(Node("d",1))
#print(tom.popHighestValue().value)

def getAll(currentNode):
    print(currentNode.value)
    if(currentNode.getChildren != []):
        for sibling in currentNode.getChildren():
            sibling.priority = 1
            return getAll(sibling)
```

The tree should look like:

```
DD
/\
a  b
/
c
```

But only DD->a->c are being hit. I thought the for loop state would be saved and continued after DD -> c was traversed.

The goal is that every node in the tree is hit. And the priority value is set to 1.

Comment: It should be `getAll(tom)`

Comment: @KireetiK That will cause infinite recursion, since it doesn't go deeper in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

A `return` statement always exits the current function. If you're in a loop when you do this, the rest of the loop is never executed.

If you need to return all the values of the recursive calls, you need to collect them in a list during the loop, then return that list after the loop is done.

But in this case there doesn't seem to be anything you need to return. This function is just for setting an attribute, there's nothing being extracted. So just make the recursive call without returning.

```
def getAll(currentNode):
    print(currentNode.value)
    for sibling in currentNode.getChildren():
        sibling.priority = 1
        getAll(sibling)
```

BTW, this won't set the priority of the root node, since it only sets the priority of children. If you want to include the root node, it should be:

```
def getAll(currentNode):
    print(currentNode.value)
    currentNode.priority = 1
    for sibling in currentNode.getChildren():
        getAll(sibling)
```

Also, you shouldn't call `getAll()` in the `getChildren()` method. It just return `self.children`, not `self.children.getAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the return before calling `getAll()` and place it outside the enclosing for loop, that would fix your problem.

In your code, you are unable to process all the children because right after your first iteration you call `getAll()` with the `return` statement. So, all the other siblings except first are/will not be explored at every depth.

Comment: There's no need for it outside the loop, the function will return when it gets to the end.

Comment: Yeah,true. But it's presence doesn't affect the functionality of the function, right?

Comment: No, it doesn't, it will be redundant.